# Execute shell command with variable with spaces

Tags: linux, svn, bash, variables, properties

I get an error (*Not a working copy*) executing a svn command in a bash script. I want to read a file containing file names. These file names get processed in the script. Each file name is on a separate line. Because some paths contain spaces the script fails. Here's a snippet of the script and file. I've tried several things, like escaping the spaces in the file, and using (dubble) quotes around the variables, but still no luck.

**Script:**
    `while read line

       do

         echo "Line = $line"

         svn propset svn:needs-lock yes $line

      done <$1`

**File:**
    `/tmp/svntmp/bi/tags/SCR-400/framework/customdata.xml

    /tmp/svntmp/bi/tags/SCR-400/framework/model.xml

    /tmp/svntmp/bi/tags/SCR-400/framework/Preferences.xml

    /tmp/svntmp/bi/tags/SCR-400/framework/Repository.xml

    /tmp/svntmp/bi/tags/SCR-462/standaard\\ overzichten/Standaard\\ CPI\\ \\(Cliënten\\ productie\\ intramuraal\\)/CPI017\\ ZZP\\ productie\\ per\\ client\\ per\\ OE.xml

...`

**Output:**
`...

Line = /tmp/svntmp/bi/tags/3.2.0.6/standaard\ overzichten/Standaard\ CZA\ \(CliÃ«nten\ zorg\ algemeen\)/CZA001\ Wachtlijst\ bewoning.xml

svn: warning: '/tmp/svntmp/bi/tags/3.2.0.6/standaard\' is not under version control

svn: 'overzichten' is not a working copy

svn: 'overzichten' does not exist

...`

Please advise on how to resolve this. Thanks.

Regards,

Johan-Kees

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use double quotes when appropriate.

```
svn propset svn:needs-lock yes "$line"
```

Do note that if your file really does look like that then this will choke regardless, for other reasons.

Comment: I've tried the dubble quotes, but still no luck. What other reasons do you mean?

Comment: All those backslashes in the file.

Comment: That was the problem. In trying to resolve the problem, I created a new one... Thanks.